# How to count columns in mysql using wamp

Tags: mysql, wamp

How could I count my table columns using wamp
I've tried this but nothing works. I've search any where but no wamp examples

```
My database = maw
My table = mist2

ID/Name/Gender/
2 /foo / M
1 /foo1/ F

2 will be the output

result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*)FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE mist2 AND maw");

result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C WHERE table_name = 'mist2'AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'maw'");

result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(AccountNumber) WHERE mist2");
```

Comment: Stop searching for `wamp` examples. Search for `sql`. All you need is `SELECT COUNT(ID) AS countId FROM maw.mist2`

Comment: You want to count columns or rows?

Comment: @Kermit Thank you so much all i searched on Google didn't have a database.table... It works perfectly